# How to apply C++ preprocessor to a C++ header file on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, c-preprocessor

I tried to apply preprocessor to a C++ header file with Macros using the below command.

```
$ g++ -E heap.h
```

And I wasn't able to get the preprocessed header file, because preprocessing was finished with the below error.

> ...
>       ...
>       # 9 "heap.h" 2
>       heap.h:10:28: fatal error: src/allocation.h: No such file or directory

To tell g++ about the directories that includes header file included in heap.h, I typed the below command, but it showed the same error.

```
$ g++ -E heap.h -I .
...
...
heap.h:10:28: fatal error: src/allocation.h: No such file or directory
```

Can you leave the solution of this problem if you have an experience that you solve this problem?

Comment: You just need to make sure you put the correct path(s) after your `-I` directive(s) so that g++ can find `src/allocation.h` and any other required includes.

Comment: please include the full commands without changing them. The `...` parts in your question might also help identify where things go wrong.

Comment: To format your question, you can put four spaces in front of lines that are from a terminal or from source code. I find that this helps readability.

Comment: Thanks, amenthes!  I followed your recommendation.

Comment: @PaulR heap.h and allocation.h stay in the same directory, so I put "-I ."

Comment: `heap.h and allocation.h stay in the same directory` looks like you use `#include "src/allocation.h"` inside your sources. If you inside `src` directory, try change directory one level up and launch command from there: `g++ -E src/heap.h -I src`.

Comment: You welcome! But headline of your question looks like wrong. In headline you ask about `... preprocessor to a c++ source file ...`, but inside topic you ask about `... preprocessor to a C++ header file ...`.

Answer (score 2):

The steps:

1. You may need to change to the directory from where your build system invokes the command if the command does not use absolute paths.
2. Copy the compiler command line from your make/cmake/etc. output.
3. Add `-E` switch.
4. Add/change `-o` parameter to `<source>.i`.